# On irreducible representations of an algebra.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$  be a complex algebra (with "nice" properties) and let  $p : A \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ be an irreducible representation of $A$  with $V $ a finite dimensional complex vector space.

Is it true that the image of $p$ is $\operatorname{End}(V)$?

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83705/surjectivity-of-irreducible-representation). It is the density theorem stating that this is true if the ground field is algebraically closed (which is of course true for $\mathbb{C}$). A proof of which can e.g. be found [Etingof et al.: Introduction to representation theory, Corollary 2.4](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0827v5.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew such a theorem cannot be wrong...

Comment: The reference is also very helpfull!

Comment: You're welcome. And if you found it helpful you can accept it by clicking on the check mark ✓ next to it